# I have Apache Tomcat 7 with Apache web server where should I keep my favicon.ico

Tags: apache, tomcat7

I have hosted a web application as ROOT under tomcat7. I have configured Apache Tomcat 7 with Apache Http server. Following is my virtual host configuration. Now I would like to host some static html along with favicon.ico. What changes do I need to make so that static some html files are served using Apache Web Server.

```
<VirtualHost 68.169.54.229:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
SuexecUserGroup dipu dipu 
CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    JkMount /* ajp13 
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question by reading the documentation here [tomcat webserver howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html). Only thing I needed to add is JkUnmount.

```
   JkUnMount /*.ico  ajp13
   JkUnMount /info/*  ajp13
```

Comment: Excellent and clean!  Hopefully I will stop getting those annoying favicon errors now from apache and tomcat.